# PHP print MySQL query in descending order

Tags: php, mysql

Code :

```
<?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("mysql17.000webhost.com","username","pwd","db");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ChatBox");
    Print "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
    Print "<table border cellpadding=3 style='text-align:left;width:auto;left:auto;right:auto;display:inline-block;'>"; 
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
    { 
    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<th>User : </th> <td>".$info['User'] . " </td>";
    Print "<th>Content : </th> <td>".$info['Content'] . " </td></tr>";
    } 
    Print "</table></div>";
```

Using this code, it will print it in the order of **the time of the content added**, which I want is to print it in the order of **opposite of the time of the content added.**

e.g.

**before adding content**
db:

```
User | Content
ABC  | Hello1
DEF  | Hello2
```

**after adding content**

```
User | Content
ABC  | Hello1
DEF  | Hello2
GHI  | Hello3
```

using this code it will print

```
User : ABC
Content : Hello1
User : EFG
Content : Hello2
User : GHI
Content : Hello3
```

and what is expected to be printed after adding content to sql database :

```
User : GHI
Content : Hello3
User : EFG
Content : Hello2
User : ABC
Content : Hello1
```

## **How can I print this result? Can anybody provide the code?**

Comment: Sidenote: You have a missing quote in your second line of code. Plus, you're mixing two MySQL APIs.

Comment: Please reopen this question. I have edited it and I hope that it will fit the rules in the help center.

Comment: Does [**my answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23013475/) not do what you're asking? See my **edit** under my code for output results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *"Using this code, it will print it in the order of the time of the content added, which I want is to print it in the order of opposite of the time of the content added."*

What you will need to do then, is create a column with a date/time value and sort it based on that column; if that's what you're asking. If not, continue with my answer below.

---

#### Original answer

First, you're mixing two MySQL APIs

`mysql_connect_error()` which should read as `mysqli_connect_error()` --- Using `mysql_connect_error()` would not have given you any error message(s), should there be any.

Plus, you're missing a quote in `"username` (as a sidenote).

Use [`ORDER BY`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)  `column DESC`

```
<?php
    $db=mysqli_connect("xxx","xxx","xxx","xxx");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $result = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ChatBox ORDER BY User DESC");
    Print "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
    Print "<table border cellpadding=3 style='text-align:left;width:auto;left:auto;right:auto;display:inline-block;'>"; 
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
    { 
    Print "<tr>";
    Print "<th>User : </th> <td>".$info['User'] . " </td>";
    Print "<th>Content : </th> <td>".$info['Content'] . " </td></tr>";
    } 
    Print "</table></div>";
```

---

**Edit:**

This is what gets printed from my DB, from testing. (printed in descending order)

```
User :  Louise  Content :   Sicilly
User :  Larry   Content :   Italy
User :  FRED    Content :   Planet Earth
User :  BOB     Content :   Spain
```

Comment: How to push the date to the sql database?

Comment: Can i use `date(ymdhis)`?

Comment: I created a column called "date_time" in my DB with `DATETIME` as the type. Then, I did an `INSERT INTO...` using `VALUES ('$col1','$col2','$col3',NOW())";` --- Using the `NOW()` function will enter both the time and date. @Jamie You can then do `ORDER BY date_time DESC`

Comment: You can also use TIMESTAMP or TIME if you just want the time. @Jamie

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by using the `ORDER BY` keyword in your SQL query.
For printing the results to your screen you can use echo.

For rendering HTML in your PHP code it may be easier to read if you write something like this:

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("mysql17.000webhost.com","username", "pwd", "db");
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
$result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM ChatBox ORDER BY User DESC");
?>

<div style='text-align:center;'>
<table border cellpadding=3 style='text-align:left;width:auto;left:auto;right:auto;display:inline-block;'>
<?php while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )): ?>
    <tr>
    <th>User : </th> <td><?php echo $info['User']; ?></td>
    <th>Content : </th> <td><?php echo $info['Content']; ?></td></tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
</table></div>
```

Comment: OP asks about printing, not querying. So this does not print that query in descending order, it still prints in the order the SQL query returns ascending. ;)

Answer (score 0):

by simply using `Order by`

```
mysqli_query($db,"SELECT * FROM ChatBox ORDER BY User,Content DESC; ");
```

and use `echo` to print data

**echo** - can output one or more strings

**print** - can only output one string, and returns always 1

```
    echo "<div style='text-align:center;'>";
    echo "<table border cellpadding=3 style='text-align:left;width:auto;left:auto;right:auto;display:inline-block;'>"; 
    while($info = mysqli_fetch_array( $result )) 
    { 
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<th>User : </th> <td>".$info['User'] . " </td>";
    echo "<th>Content : </th> <td>".$info['Content'] . " </td></tr>";
    } 
    echo "</table></div>";
```